# Network Sharing still blocked, even after changing group policy in windows 11

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, group-policy, windows-11

I am trying to share my network via Ethernet from my laptop to my old PC which doesn't have a wifi card. (+ I don't have a long enough ethernet cable to route to my old PC right now.)

I am currently stuck on this problem, that my laptop `(Acer Predator Helios 300 i7-8750H, Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti running Windows 11 | Wifi Card: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz)` shows Network Sharing has been disabled by the network administrator under `Sharing` even though I have disabled the policy that prohibits this in the group policy editor, following a youtube tutorial.
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkED6.png)

I don't understand why this could be, maybe something to do with VMware Workstation's network adapters, which this machine has installed, however, I don't quite get how if it is.

Here are some screenshots:

WiFi "Sharing Tab"

> [image: WiFi "Sharing Tab"]

Group Policy editor

> [image: Group Policy editor]

WiFi Connections tab in control panel

> [image: WiFi Connections tab in control panel]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: @Ramhound done.

Comment: I assume you switch them to disabled after you discovered it was prohibited? Have you tried to enable mobile Hotspot as a test. The reason is that the policy in question also prevents that, using a mobile hotspot, is only a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post
[Internet Connection Sharing has been disabled by the Network Administrator – Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10](https://xvii.com.au/windows/internet-connection-sharing-has-been-disabled-by-the-network-administrator-windows-8/)
has an answer:

> 1. Start > Run > gpedit.msc
> 2. Navigate to Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Network/Network Connections
> 3. Disable the following policies:
>
>    - *Prohibit installation and configuration of Network Bridge on your DNS domain network*
>    - *Prohibit use of Internet Connection Firewall on your DNS domain network*
>    - *Prohibit use of Internet Connection Sharing on your DNS domain network*
>    - *Require domain users to elevate when setting a network’s location*
> 4. Start > Run > regedit
>
> - Locate `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections`
>
>   - If this key doesn’t exist, it may be disabled by means other than group policy.
>
> 5. Add/update a registry DWORD entry for the following, and set it to 1;
>
>    - *NC_PersonalFirewallConfig*
>    - *NC_ShowSharedAccessUI*

Comment: Thanks, the registry part fixed it finally.